# Linux Shell script to check the $PATH variable if include a path or partial path, if not add it, if has similar path change it

Tags: unix, path

I need to add to my shell script the following functionality:

NewPath=/opt/DirA/DirB/DirC

Check the variable $PATH
if $NewPath is anywhere in the $PATH variable, do not change anything.
if the $PATH variable includes a similar path as */DirA/* where the other part of the path are different then delete that path and add $NewPath.
$NewPath can be either at the beginning of at the end of $PATH.

Alternatively can be simplified as

Check variable $PATH
if the $PATH variable includes the partial path */DirA/* anywhere then delete that path and add $NewPath.
$NewPath can be either at the beginning of at the end of $PATH.

My object is that if an existing path was already on the machine, replace it with the newest, but if I run the same script several time, I do not get the same path appended multiple times.
In my case one of the DirX would be the software version number

Ex: NewPath=/opt/DirA/Ver2.3.4/DirC while the machines where the script was running may have a older version as /opt/DirA/Ver1.2.3/DirC

Thanks

---

Thanks for the comments, here in more details.
In the sample below, I am looking for a way to remove the wrong path where somesim is the only part that I know is always there, The part with PROG can be anything in different servers.

```
    PROGPath="/opt/some/PROG_Ver_123/somesim/linux_x86_64"

    if [[ "$PATH" == *"PROG_Ver_123"* ]]; then
        echo "PROG_Ver_123 is alredy there, do nothing."
    elif [[ "$PATH" == *"somesim"* ]]; then
        echo "Wrong Version of somesim, remove it and replace with Correct one"
        # here I need to remove the full path of somesim, it can be anywhere
        # therefore : can be before, after or on both sides
        export PATH=$PROGPath:$PATH
    else
        echo "No somesim path found, adding it"
        export PATH=$PROGPath:$PATH
    fi
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the [tour] and [ask].  Do not expect members here to write the script for you.  We can help with specific issues, after you have demonstrated you have done some work, and extensive research.  You are expected to profice a [mcve] of the specific issue you are facing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

with try and error I got the results I needed as follow

```
PROGPath="/opt/some/PROG_Ver_123/somesim/linux_x86_64"

if [[ "$PATH" == *"$PROGPath"* ]]; then
    echo "Correct Path already included, do nothing."
elif [[ "$PATH" == *"somesim"* ]]; then
    echo "Wrong Version of somesim, Replace with Correct one"
    NEWPATH=$(echo $PATH | sed "s+/opt/some/.*/somesim/linux_x86_64+$PROGPath+g")
    export PATH=$NEWPATH
else
    echo "Path missing, adding it"
    export PATH=$PROGPath:$PATH
fi
```

Comment: I think you will not have a problem in your situation, but be aware of the greedy nature of `sed`. The `.*` will be matched with as much as possible: The PATH `/opt/some/thing/else:/var/log/somesim/linux_x86_64000` will turn into `/opt/some/PROG_Ver_123/somesim/linux_x86_64000`.